# Компонентный подход React + D3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Доброго времени суток

Использую D3 с React'ом через react-faux-dom. Возникла идея создавать D3 компоненты и грузить их через реакт компоненты, но ошибок никаких нет и просто выводит пустой svg.

Накидал простенький пример.
Структура вот такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл Brush.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { withFauxDOM } from "react-faux-dom";

const Brush = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select("svg")
      .append("g")
      .call(d3.brushX().extent([[0, 0], [200, 200]]));
  });
  return;
};

export default withFauxDOM(Brush);
```

Файл G.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { withFauxDOM } from "react-faux-dom";

const G = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select("svg").append("g");
  });
  return;
};

export default withFauxDOM(G);
```

Файл Svg.js:

```
import ReactFauxDOM, { withFauxDOM } from "react-faux-dom";

const Svg = () => {
  const createSVG = new ReactFauxDOM.createElement("svg");

  return createSVG.toReact();
};

export default withFauxDOM(Svg);
```

Файл App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Svg from "./Components/Svg";
import G from "./Components/G";
import Brush from "./Components/Brush";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Svg>
      <G>
        <Brush />
      </G>
    </Svg>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Ну и в index.js просто делаем ReactDOM.render

Буду признателен любой подсказке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что из компонентов wrappers, которые расположены над вложенными компонентами ничего не возвращается. Надо попробовать добавить return **props.children;**

```
const G = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select("svg").append("g");
  });
  return props.children;
};
```